# Adding Custom Fields to a Custom Post Type, the Right Way

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i'm create a custom post type and i also add a custom field for add something. so, my problem is that "How can i show this field value in my website" ?

```
 'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
```

i already tried this one. but it's not working.

```
<?= get_field( 'field_name' ); ?>
```

Comment: hey try  `<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>` to get CF values.

Comment: thanks . but i also try this one.

Comment: have  you used an ACF plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is `get_post_meta()`. See this docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Your `get_field` is a specific function for Advanced Custom Fields plugin. It's only available when you install it.

Each custom fields has its own helper functions to get and display field values. For example, Meta Box uses `rwmb_meta` function.

If you use any of them, be sure that follow their documentation.